# How to send a message to multiple recipients in react native

Tags: react-native

I am implementing an application which sends SMS to multiple recipients from react native app for IOS.

I am using this library
[React-native-communication](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications)

please answer this question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#openurl) from 'react-native':

```
const onPressSendMessage = () => {
  let numbers = '';

  contacts.forEach((phoneNumber: string) => {
    numbers += `${phoneNumber},`;
  });
  numbers = numbers.slice(0, -1);

  const url = (Platform.OS === 'android')
    ? `sms:${numbers}?body=${text}`
    : `sms:/open?addresses=${numbers}&body=${text}`;

  Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((supported: boolean) => {
    if (!supported) {
      console.log('Unsupported url: ', url);
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(url).then(() => {
        navigateBack(); // or something else
      });
    }
  }).catch((err: string) => console.log('An error occurred', err));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [react-native-sms](https://github.com/tkporter/react-native-sms) package?

Its `SMS.send` function supports an options parameter that can handle multiple recipients. https://github.com/tkporter/react-native-sms#using-the-module